# How to convert .epub to .pdb for testing

Tags: epub, conversion, pdb

I've seen some conversion sites that can convert `.epub` files to `.pdb` files but I was unaware of a source library or a way to convert a file locally for testing on the Nook.  So my question is: Do you know of a library or a way to convert an `.epub` file to a `.pdb` file to test on a Nook?  I would like to do this without using Calibre.

Comment: Why not use Calibre? If bugs have you reported them or ask here how to work round

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an old program called TL-PDB. The original authors site seems to be [here](http://download.enet.com.cn/) according to [this site](http://download.enet.com.cn/html/EN455462005081001.html), but I have some difficulty reading the original.

You can read about it [here](http://www.freewarepalm.com/utilities/tl-pdb.shtml) and [here](http://tl-pdb.en.softonic.com/palm) as well (download sites for free software seem to copy each others content).

Calibre can generate [PDB](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#id13) output (not surprisingly as MOBI is a superset of PalmDoc).

Comment: Edited my question, not a fan of the bloating Calibre provides and the inaccuracy it causes.  +1 though for the answer.

Comment: @Gramps Is it the install that bothers you, if it is the GUI that bothers you: you can do the conversion on the commandline.

Comment: @Gramps The format for PalmDoc, IIRC is not so difficult. Would you consider writing  something yourself (or at least helping to debug)?

Comment: No its the bloat and errors that bothers me with Calibre..  I hate the unnecessary bloating and splitting of content I see.  I also dislike when I'm sent a Calibre book and it has generated a single `.html` file and `.css` file for each page.  Plus Calibre doesn't produce a valid `.epub` most of the time.  I have considered writing my own and might create a tutorial for it one day but lately I've been slammed.

Comment: Calibre;s split is because some epub readers have a limit on the html size - I would like to see where it has a html file per page and where the epub is invalid

Answer (score 1):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) offers `.pdb` as both input and output [file types](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#what-formats-does-app-support-conversion-to-from).  This should meet your requirements, for converting from `.epub` to `.pdb`.

Comment: LOL, so as I am writing my answer (with links) the existing answer and the question are both edited...

Comment: ha ha sorry man..  thanks for the effort though